# Is there a modernized way of getting a weak self reference for blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I see old sample code use this code a lot:

```
__unsafe_unretained __block AssetItem *weakSelf = (AssetItem *)self;
```

I remember that something has changed and this became easier. So is there now a modernized way of doing this?

Comment: [Blocks are implemented as objects](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#blocks-as-objects). You can use __block __weak.

Comment: mmackh is right. For Apple references, see [Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16) or "Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles" section of the [Transitioning To ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```